# dojo/mvc/at doesn't return dijit/form/DateTextBox in format of constraints datePattern

Tags: dojo, dijit.form

This seem's to be a question often asked, but there doesn't seem to be an easy answer or an answer at all, so I risk a duplicate here, and ask again - I feel like having a puzzle with 4 pieces and don't manage to put them together:

I'm using a dojo date picker like this

```
<input data-dojo-type="dijit/form/DateTextBox" 
       data-dojo-props="constraints: { datePattern: 'yyyy-MM-dd'},
                        value: at(model, 'myDate')" />
```

The date picker displays the date in UI like I want, but the value that's assigned in `model.myDate` keeps being in ISO format - I'd need that to be in `yyyy-MM-dd`, too.

I know that I can use `dojo.date.locale.format` to post-process the value, but that would be after it is saved in `model.myDate`. I'd like to return the value in the correct format right away. Return value `null` if there's no input, return value `undefined` if there's no valid value, and return value in format `yyyy-MM-dd` when the given date is valid.

Maybe I can integrate that call to `dojo.date.locale.format` somehow? Something like `.transform(..)` or whatever is possible in dojo!?

I also read about overwriting the `serialize` method, but I don't see how and where to do that in here.

Any ideas or hint in the right direction? Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Hi just wondering if something like `at(model, prop).transform(converterObj)` helps: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/mvc/at.html#data-converter

Comment: In the linked example, the value taken from the date picker is transformed to be displayed in another input - the `model.myDate` would still have the wrong format (I think) - so how can I use this `transform()` to reflect my date pattern in `model.myDate`?

Comment: Hi you can write your own `format()`/`parse()` functions.